# AT COMMAND's GC433-TC016 No Response

Tags: wireless, at-commands, serialport

My question consurns AT Commands using a Serial Port Wireless Device.  ( SILICONRA - microchip )  GC433-TC016. I can transmit and receive Serial Port transmissions to Remote units. ( GC433-TC016)
I have 8 of them they all transmit and receive fine. I have tried everything to get it to accept AT Commands, I can send Commands to an ESP8266 ESP-01 and it works.   Here is what I am trying to Send:  AT+RFCH=\r\n  (RFCH:0~40\r\n). I just need to be able to change CHANNELs. I have tried every command on this unit and have never gotten a response from any Command.
AT+RFCH=1\r\n   AT+RFCH=01\r\n   AT+RFCH=1 + 0xD + 0xA, Sent all in one line or Each Charater Seperately. BAUD: 9600 STOP BIT:0 The DataSheet is mostly in Chinese but I was able to translate every word. I have sent commands using Cool Terminal, My Own VB Program VB.net and Vb6. I am using a USB to Serial Port TTL converter. I also am using my own PIC18f2550 Serial Port.
If I change the BAUD rate even just  300 points I can no longer Transmit and Receive, so I know my  Serial Port is Communicating with the Module. I have also tried changing the Input State of the RESET , ENABLE, SWDCLK and the SWDIO lines just in case. I have sent emails to the company 3 times in both English and Chinese, No response. Has anyone had experience with this or other Modules by this Company ( SILICONRA - microchip ) GC433-TC016.  I have been trying for several Months to get this to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It took awhile but I finally got a response from SILICONRA - microchip. To get into the Command Mode, send AT+MODE=0\r\n Then you can send the Commands. Such as AT+RFCH=0\r\n to be able to change the channel. When completing any or all Commands you must EXIT Command Mode = AT+MODE=1\r\n   Using the PIC18F2550 Uart lines required a very precise baud rate. I have 2 separate applications using the Pic18f on one: the Uart rate was fine without any delays after sending Each Letter of the Commands, on the other module I had to insert a Delay After Each Letter of the Commands. Took awhile but I was finally able to get both to work with Commands. Their is a slight Delay receiving an OK response, I just Inserted a Delay, instead of Verifying an OK response.